# GAE Guestbook Java tutorial. force authentication of /sign servlet causes 405 on redirect

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, post

I've gone throught the guestbook tutorial and I've been trying to force authentication for the /sign servlet.  Here's what I've put in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sign</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.demos.guestbook.SignGuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sign</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/sign</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>sign</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/sign/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When attempting to sign the guestbook I get redirected to the login screen correctly but once I click on "Log In" I get the following error

```
Error 405 HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
```

So it seems like the redirect is a GET instead of a POST.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the core of your issue is that when the user is redirected to the Google login page, Google doesn't really hand them back to your application using a POST, I think it will simply be a GET, so in summary I doubt the Google login will preserve your original POST signature and replay it back to your application once the user is authenticated. So one approach you can go about this is to hide the sign form if the user is not logged in and show then a message asking them to click the login link. For example on guestbook.jsp from line 80:

```
<%
if (user != null) {
%>
  <form action="/sign" method="post">
    <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Post Greeting"/></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="guestbookName" value="${fn:escapeXml(guestbookName)}"/>
  </form>
<%
} else {
%>
    <span>Please login first to be able to sign the guestbook (click the login link above)</span>
<%
}
%>
```

I've not tested this by the way.

Other more involved option I had to use in the past is to use a filter in front of the servlet, remember the user's original request in the session, formulate the login url, redirect the user to it, once the user is back handle their original request, but this is complex so in your case you better off explicitly ask the user to authenticate first

Comment: This is definitely a feasible workaround.  I'll play around with that.  Ideally I can get a full fix.  The behavior I'm trying to emulate above is pretty common.